# MongoClient.connect only once

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-scraping, puppeteer

So in the following functions I'm always establishing a new connection with my mongodb. How would I have to change my code so it only connects once at the beginning and not in every of these functions.

```
function getData(callback){
arrayOfArticles = [];
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, callback, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let dbo = db.db('testdb');
    article = dbo.collection('testname').find({}).toArray(function(err, article) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.close();
        for (var i = 0, len = article.length; i < len; i++){
            arrayOfArticles.push(article[i].name);
        }
        callback(null, arrayOfArticles);
    });
});



function getPrice(callback){
arrayOfPrices = [];
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, callback, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let dbo = db.db('testdb');
    article = dbo.collection('testcollection').find({}).toArray(function(err, arrayOfPrices) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.close();
        callback(null, arrayOfPrices);
    });
});




function getDealerData(callback){
dealerData = [];
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, callback, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let dbo = db.db('Dealer');
    article = dbo.collection('Dealer').find({}).toArray(function(err, dealerData) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.close();
        callback(null, dealerData);
    });
});
```

Comment: specify `MongoClient.connect` in your main server file

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I don't have a main server file, its just a node application for some web scraping

Comment: Put `MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });` outside of all function. That should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a good practice to create connection for every task.

I would suggest to create a separate file for create connection and available the connection on everywhere

Example

//db.js

```
MongoClient.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
}, callback, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  global.dbo = db.db('testdb');
});
```

And in your main server file I am assuming `app.js` and require it on top for all middlewares

```
//app.js
<--All depandent module -->

require('db.js'); // change the path according to your structure.
```

And now `dbo` will be available to all your app and just use it everywhere.

> It's also good practice to use single connection and for load, Mongo itself creates pull to handle the concurrency
>
> As per Mongo official comment:
>
> You open do `MongoClient.connect` once when your app boots up and reuse the db object. It's not a singleton connection pool each .connect creates a new connection pool. So open it once an reuse across all requests.

***Update***

I have tried to make your one function here

```
function getPrice(callback){
  arrayOfPrices = [];
  dbo.collection('testcollection').find({}).toArray(function(err, arrayOfPrices) {
    if (err) throw err;
    callback(null, arrayOfPrices);
});
}
```

Comment: How would I exchange MongoClient.connect to dbConnection for example in my first function?

Comment: Your function is tightly coupled so, just remove all connections code from each function and create separate file for connection and directly use it in your all functions, and also I have updated the variable name with your variable name

Comment: Yeah I got that part, it's just that I can't figure out how to just remove the connections code from each function without destroying it.

Comment: I have tried to update one function, you can test rest of the things

Comment: so I tried updating all functions and exporting the external connection file like this  `module.export.dbsesconnect = function dbsesconnect () { 
  MongoClient.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    global.dbo = db.db('ProjectGoldmine');
  });  
}; ` and importing it like this `let mongoconnect = require('./databaseconnect');
mongoconnect.dbsesconnect();` and get the error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'dbsesconnect' of undefined"

Comment: you no need to use `module.exports` you can copy paste my db.js file code and require mongo module and run it

Comment: mean your query code executing first then your db code executing.
make sure your db code execute first, you can define in your server file at top of the file and below the modules as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: I think the structure of my js files is really bad, having a hard time to require the files correctly. Going to need some time to restructure everything

Answer (score 1):

I found this block of code, derived from the previous answer to be very useful...

Rather than a separate file it stores the collection in the app locals system.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(client => {
  const dbo = client.db('myDB');
  const collection = dbo.collection('numbers');
  app.listen(port2, () => console.info(`REST API running on port ${port2}`));
  app.locals.collection = collection; // this line stores the collection from above so it is available anywhere in the app, after small delay.
}).catch(error => console.error(error));
```